# How to add an image in a calculated list column

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I want to use and image instead of a text in a field. see this image [image]The edit column its a calculated column. If users click on it. It will opens the editform.aspx.
So i want to use an image instead of have a text labelled Edit. but clicking on the image should also open the editform.aspx. Here's the custom code of the calculated column:

="http://mysharepointwebsite/myhomepage/_layouts/FormServer.aspx?XmlLocation=/cours/form/Request%20no%20"&NumRequest&".xml&ClientInstalled=false&Source=https%3A%2F%2mywebsite%2Ehec%2Eca%2Fmypage%2FForm%2FForms%2FMy%2520Requests%2520from%2520today%2Easpx&DefaultItemOpen=1'>Edit"

Comment: Can't you just add the Edit field to your view? Edit the view and tick the Edit field, this is standard built in functionality.

Comment: I will try this thankyou . I already have a view with the edit field i will try your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Calculated field in list and add this type of formula

```
="<a href='https://<Domain>.sharepoint.com/Lists/date%20diff/EditForm.aspx?ID="&ID&"'><img src='/SiteAssets/edit.png' style='height:20px; width:20px;'/></a>"
```

[image]