# Open link in a calculated field in New window

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, calculated-column, hyperlink

I have a list that has a calculated Column fied. Below is the code for that field. The field shows "Display" as a link to the users. When people click on that link a form is open. But i want that link to open in a new window. How can i modify this code below to achieve that

```
="<a href=https://mywebsite.mydomain.com/sitename/_layouts/Print.FormServer.aspx?XmlLocation=/sitename/ListName/Request%20no%20"&RequestNum&".xml&ClientInstalled=false&Source=http%3A%2F%2mywebsite%2Emydomain%2Ecom%2Fsitename%2FListName%2FForms%2FAllItems%2Easpx&DefaultItemOpen=1> Display</a>"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add an image in a calculated list column](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/199659/how-to-add-an-image-in-a-calculated-list-column)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `target="_blank"` to **`<a>`** tag to can open link at new window it should look like

```
="<a target='_blank' href='https://mywebsite.mydomain.com/sitename/_layouts/Print.FormServer.aspx?XmlLocation=/sitename/ListName/Request%20no%20"&RequestNum&".xml&ClientInstalled=false&Source=http%3A%2F%2mywebsite%2Emydomain%2Ecom%2Fsitename%2FListName%2FForms%2FAllItems%2Easpx&DefaultItemOpen=1' > Display</a>"
```